# entitymanager get null when configure arquillian with wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am new to the arquillian, and got a problem above.
here is my pom.xml:
https://github.com/langker/LendingPlat/blob/master/pom.xml

here is the  arquillian.xml(also I am not sure if this file has been read, because when I changed the value ,nothing new happen):
https://github.com/langker/LendingPlat/blob/master/src/main/java/META-INF/arquillian.xml

And the test code is here:
https://github.com/langker/LendingPlat/blob/master/src/test/java/me/langker/LendingPlat/test/UserTest.java

while the error track is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at me.langker.LendingPlat.Dao.UserDao.findByEmail(UserDao.java:26)  
at me.langker.LendingPlat.Controller.UserController.reg(UserController.java:36)  
at me.langker.LendingPlat.test.UserTest.testName(UserTest.java:19)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)  
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)  
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:374)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.protocol.local.LocalContainerMethodExecutor.invoke(LocalContainerMethodExecutor.java:50)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:367)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:245)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:259)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:319)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:312)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)  
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)  
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)  
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)  
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)  
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)  
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)  
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)  
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)  
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)  
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) `


I think the reason is that the Arquillian has not connect to the wildfly right, so the entitymanager get null, but I don't know how to fix it.

thank you all in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,I solved finally. I edited the pom.xml like this and it worked.

https://github.com/langker/LendingPlat/blob/c3d79e71d907cc26d98fe855d2c3c65cfa994b04/pom.xml